# Summing $\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{a^4}+\frac{1}{a^9}-\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, asymptotics

This question comes from [temperature at sphere center](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208973/find-an-expression-for-the-heat-at-the-centre-of-the-sphere-with-temperature-mo). I think it's a good idea to extract the essence and post a pure mathematical question to attract more thoughts. It is a physical problem and interested readers can go to the original post to find details.

Anyway, after simplification the wanted value is $2 f(x)$

$$
f(x)= - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n e^{-x n^2} 
$$
Letting $x = \pi^2 D t /a^2$ gives the answer to the original question. If we further let $e^{x} = a$, we have a summation problem:

$$
S=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n a^{-n^2} = \frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{a^4}+\frac{1}{a^9}-\cdots
$$

$a > 1$ so $S$ converges, but I don't now how to sum it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @i8Σπ_821 Could you be more specific? That's not a geometric series.

Comment: Ah yes it's not. I will delete my comment. Apologies.

Comment: @i8Σπ_821 Hi, no problem :-)

Comment: Taozi: I've never heard of that function that Misha mentioned, but it's interesting :-)

Comment: @i8Σπ_821 I just posted an answer to the original physical problem. The link to is in the first sentence of my question. I plotted a figure there.

Comment: Taozi: Yes I saw your link. That's a nice way of interpreting the OP's problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can write this sum in terms of the [Jacobi theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) $\vartheta(z;\tau)$; in particular, I believe that
$$\vartheta(\tfrac12;\tfrac{ix}{\pi}) = 1 - 2f(x).$$
That's not an answer: it's just saying "we don't know how to find this sum in terms of functions we know about, so we gave this sum a name".

But maybe looking at the Wikipedia article I linked to will give you some idea of what can be done with the function to find the things about it you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a beautiful function that I've never heard of.